# SQL to linq translating query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, ms-access

I'm trying to translate ans sql query to linq. But i'm having difficulties! Anybody willing to help? :)

```
SELECT MOV.ORIGINE AS origine, TAX.ID as codice, TAX.descrizione, Sum(IIF(MOV.INCREMENTA,0,MOV.IMPORTO)) AS importi, Sum(IIF(MOV.INCREMENTA,-MOV*IMPORTO,0)) AS sconti, Sum(IIF(MOV.INCREMENTA,-1,1)*MOV.IMPORTO) AS  totale
FROM (MOV INNER JOIN TAX ON (MOV.COD_TAX = TAX.ID) AND (MOV.ORIGINE = TAX.ORIGINE))
WHERE MOV.DATA BETWEEN [@F] AND [@T] AND TAX.CONTEGGIO
GROUP BY MOV.ORIGINE, TAX.ID, TAX.DESCRIZIONE, TAX.IMPONIBILE
ORDER BY MOV.ORIGINE DESC, TAX.IMPONIBILE
```

mov and tax are represented in my program by two datatables already filled with proper data

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: search for http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: var result = from mov in movDatatable join tax in taxDatatable on mov.origine equals tax.origine
where (mov.cod_tax = tax.id && mov.data >= data1 && mov.data <= data2 && tax.conteggio)
orderby mov.origine descending, tax.imponibile


but now i don't know how to apply the group logic

Comment: may be you need to group by an Anonymous object here..